# How many combination possible with 5 bits while 2 are always on (1)

Tags: math, binary, formula

I am looking for a formula to calculate the number of combinations possible for 5 bits with the constraint that 2 bits should always be on (1) and 3 off (0). e.g. 10010, 11000, 00101,... etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is worth to google your phrase `number of combinations` to get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination , learn abount binomial coefficient formula, get value 20

Comment: the link is perfect, thanks. But I got the value 10 in the end (using the factorial formula).

Comment: Yes, my mistake ;)

Comment: Could you please clarify your problem? Do you want only combinations with exactly 2 bits on and 3 bits off, or any combination with at least 2 bits on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 5 choices for the position of the first `(1)` bit and after that you have 4 choices for the position of the second `(1)` bit. It gives total `5*4` variants, but this way we counted each combination twice, hence we should divide this value by `2`.

The formula is `5*4/2=10`.